# What's the difference between a mean model and a variance model in ugarchspec (in R)

Tags: r, garch, arch

In R, when you run a (G)ARCH, within the 'ugarchspec', there is a 'mean model' argument as well as a 'variance model' argument. I was wondering what the difference is (couldn't find if this was asked before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 
$$
y_t = \mu_t + \sigma_t\varepsilon_t
$$
with $\varepsilon_t \sim i.i.d(0,1)$, then the `mean.model` will specify what $\mu_t$ is while `variance.model` will specify what $\sigma_t$ is. For example,

- $\mu_t = \varphi_1 y_{t-1}$ would imply an AR(1) conditional mean model, and
- $\sigma_t^2 = \omega + \alpha_1 (\sigma_{t-1} \varepsilon_{t-1})^2$ would imply an ARCH(1) conditional variance model.

Comment: Gotcha! Cheers!